# freshclam not working because clamav folder in /var/log and /var/log is in ramdisk

Tags: log, clamav, tmpfs

I was looking for this on the web but since English is not my primary language it seems that I can not find what I want, that is why my question is here...

**Intro**:

I have an SSD and I did some optimization procedures from these sites: [Site1](http://apcmag.com/how-to-maximise-ssd-performance-with-linux.htm) and [Site2](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd). And I have to say everything works OK, sometimes some things are lost because of tmpfs modifications.

My optimizations include mounting tmpfs's for folders as per instructions on these sites and one particular folder */var/log* is used by ClamAV for storing its log folder and update log file -> */var/log/clamav/freshclam.log*.

Now every time I reboot system, that folder */var/log/clamav* is lost and `freshclam` command is not working and clamav returns errors about logging. I have to add folder *clamav* and file *freshclam.log* to */var/log* manually and then `freshclam` command works and updates my clamav definitions ...

**Question**:

Is there any way that I set that folder and file to reappear after system reboot (because I see that there are some default folders made on system startup and they are reappearing after every reboot; they appear empty but nevertheless they are there!)?

P.S.: If I was not clear enough about problem or question I will explain again. If you need to see how my */etc/fstab* file looks like I can post its contents ...

Thank you in forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to see your fstab. However, if you are mounting your /var/log in /tmpfs then it is not a surprise that you are losing the files you are mounting there at every reboot.

Comment: I have edited /etc/rc.local and folder is reappearing after reboot, now I just need to find a way to create file -> freshclam.log in that folder.

Comment: The file should be automatically created when you start clamav. The directive is placed in `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf`. Look for a directive which looks like this `LogFile /var/log/clamav/clamav.log`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hope the solution worked for you.